# Amazon linux: No package pgbouncer available

Tags: pgbouncer, amazon-linux

trying to install pgbouncer on amazon met this:

```
[root@somehost ~]# uname -a
Linux somehost 4.4.35-33.55.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 20:30:04 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@somehost ~]# yum install pgbouncer
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package pgbouncer available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Went to [github](https://pgbouncer.github.io/2016/02/pgbouncer-1-7-2) - found only compilable version. Googled and decided to post solution below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at [The PostgreSQL Global Development Group repo](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) copy link to your linux release (in my case Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03 - x86_64) and run:

```
rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-93-9.3-3.noarch.rpm
yum install pgbouncer
```

as result:

```
Installed:
  pgbouncer.x86_64 0:1.7.2-6.rhel6
```